# jQuery Aim Menu selector

Tags: jquery, drupal, menu

I am actualy trying to implement the jquery aim menu plugin on my page

What I cant handle is that drupal sets the first and secound level of the menu at the exact same classes and i have no idea what i should tell jquery to use as his selector.

I started with something like that about 3 hours ago

```
$("#main-menu").menuAim({
    activate: function(a){
        $(this).children('ul').css('display','block');
    },  // fired on row activation
    deactivate: function(a){
        $(this).children('ul').css('display','none');

    }  // fired on row deactivation
});
```

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Hey Basti, did you get it somewhat working? I am also trying to implement this functionality on a Drupal menu.

Comment: Can't you just select with 'ul' and 'li' elements? First level: li elements from ul. Second level: li elements from ul from li elements from ul. You could even add the classes on the fly with jquery.

Comment: Can you add another class or ID to the ul tag in question and have your JQuery code work based on the new class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( "#main-menu" ).addClass( "new_class" );

$(".new_class").menuAim({
    activate: function(a){
        $(this).children('ul').css('display','block');
    },  // fired on row activation
    deactivate: function(a){
        $(this).children('ul').css('display','none');

    }  // fired on row deactivation
});
```

That should ensure that there are no conflicts.